# How portYIELD works in freeRTOS

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, freertos

I'am totally beginner with freeRTOS, In freeRTOS [documentation](http://www.freertos.org/a00020.html#taskYIELD) taskYIELD is used to request a context switch, taskYIELD is defined as follow

```
#define taskYIELD()                 portYIELD()
```

and portYIELD is defined as follow :

```
#define portYIELD()                 {__asm__ __volatile__ ("scall");}
```

if i undrestand this will cause a system call exception.

In the exception.s of my port, system calls are handled as follows:

```
.org  0x100
  // Supervisor Call.
  _handle_Supervisor_Call:
  rjmp $
```

Meaning that the program will enter an infinite loop, so the question is how the program get out from this infinte loop ?
If any mistake in my undrestanding don't hesitate to comment.

Am using Atmel uc3a0512 and Atmel Studio 7.0

Comment: I haven't used FreeRTOS, but is it normal to put an infinite loop as the handler for the system-call instruction?  I suspect that the idea is to yield by making a system call which is allowed to block/schedule.  i.e. the system call handler is supposed to be something that checks if the current task has been running to long, and if so jump to the scheduler to find what the CPU should be doing right now.

Comment: Yes, indeed it's weired for me too.

Comment: Did you write that infinite loop?  If it came that way, is it something that most projects are intended to replace?

Comment: No, i didn't change anything the code am showing is extracted from a working freeRTOS example.

Answer (score 1):

What version of FreeRTOS do you use? What compiler do you use? I have versions 8.2.3 and 9.0.0. There are two ports in both of versions for AVR32 UC3: GCC and IAR.

In *FreeRTOS\Source\portable\GCC\AVR32_UC3\exception.S* we can see:

```
        .org  0x100
        // Supervisor Call.
_handle_Supervisor_Call:
        lda.w   pc, SCALLYield
```

For IAR we have kind of same code. So you can see there is the calling of `SCALLYield`. Download last version and enjoy!

Comment: it's freeRTOS 7.0.0 and AVR32/GNU Compiler, I assure you that i tried to run several tasks and it works fine, but the question is HOW all works well with the code i'am showing above?

Comment: oh-wow. Are you sure that you call `taskYIELD()` or `portYIELD()`? Check it with debugger or printf to UART! There is other way to switch context: `vTick()` that calls `vTaskSwitchContext()`

Comment: @Mouin: you didn't say in the question that it worked!!  I was assuming that it did actually enter an infinite loop like you said, and you were asking how it's supposed to break out.  (i.e. what change to the code would let it work).